# Spring Boot Webflux (reactive web app) not serving static content on file system

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

**Issue**

When setting the `spring.web.resources.static-locations` configuration as detailed in section [4.7.2 Static Content of the spring boot 2.4.2 reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.2/reference/htmlsingle/), content is not found.

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Open the [Spring Initialzr](https://start.spring.io/), select Project=Maven project, Language=Java, Spring Boot=2.4.2, Packaging=Jar, Java=8, Dependencies=Spring Reactive Web
2. Run the generated app with environment variable, the path below points to a valid folder containing an index.html file

   export SERVER_PORT=8084
   export SPRING_WEB_RESOURCES_STATICLOCATIONS=file:C:\mydev\staticlocal
   mvn spring-boot:run
3. Open http://localhost:8084 , http://localhost:8084/ or http://localhost:8084/index.html with a browser and you get a **Whitelabel Error Page**

**Alternative 1**
Repeating the steps above by setting the configuration `spring.resources.static-locations` in step 2) as below will also fail to open the linked static files:

```
export SPRING_RESOURCES_STATICLOCATIONS=file:C:\\mydev\\staticlocal
```

**Alternative 2: this works**
Repeating the steps by selecting Dependencies="Spring Web" in step 1) and setting the configuration `spring.resources.static-locations` as below will *succeed* to open the static files:

```
export SPRING_RESOURCES_STATICLOCATIONS=file:C:\\mydev\\staticlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem above stems from the shell used to execute the scenario. See details in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/25397

The Spring framework works as documented :)